# Unidirectional JPA OnetoMany Mapping - ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have two tables with schema as follows :

**Table1**

table1_id (pk) (integer)

name

**Table2**

table2_id (pk) (String)

table1_id (pk)  (integer)

name

My code looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table2")
class Table2 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "table2_id")  
    private String id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn (name="table1_id")
    private Set<Table1> table1Set = new HashSet<>();


    //setters and getters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Table1")
class Table1 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "table1_id")  
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    //setters and getters
}
```

Now when I query: `Table2Repository.findById("One")`:

I get below error:

```
Hibernate: select table2.id as table2_id_1_, table2.name as name2_1_ from table2 table20_
Hibernate: select table10_.table1_id as table1_id1_1_0_, table1_.table1_id as table1_id1_0_0_, table10_.table1_id as table1_id1_0_1_, table10_.name as name2_0_1_ from table1 table10_ where table10_.table1_id=?
2017-07-25 12:53:11.352  WARN 11572 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1722, SQLState: 42000
2017-07-25 12:53:11.352 ERROR 11572 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-01722: invalid number
```

It seems some mismatch is occuring. It seems to be using String "table2_id" to query Table1, where as it should use "table1_id"

Kindly help!

Comment: There is a name clash in your mapping: `@JoinColumn (name="table1_id")` on `Table2.table1Set` vs `@Id @Column(name = "table1_id")` on `Table1.id`. Note that the join column goes into `Table1`, **not** `Table2`.

Comment: @crizzis , I realised that the join column should be in the "many" side table ie. Table1 . However this database schema is old and modification may not be easy. Is there anyway to make it work without moving the join column to Table1 ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I follow. How can you have a *one-to-many* association with the join column on the *one* side? When there is more than one `Table1` associated to `Table2`, where are you planning to store their ids?

Comment: Ok. Let me try to explain more with an example. Consider two tables Person and Phone Number. One person can have many Phone Number.Person has Id : person_id. Phone table has id Phone_num. Now from what I understood so far for OnetoMany relation, the schema should be like : 

PERSON:
Person_id


PHONE
Phone_num
Person_id


The above works fine.
However , below schema doesn't work.Let me know if this should work. :

PERSON:
Person_id
Phone_num

PHONE
Phone_num

Comment: I understand you meant the schema comprised by `PERSON(person_id, phone_id)` and `PHONE_NUMBER(phone_id,phone_number)`. In such a schema, each `PERSON` row can only hold one value in the `phone_id` column, meaning that each person can have at most one phone number. Suppose there is an entry in the `PERSON` table with `phone_id` referencing an entry in `PHONE_NUMBER` and you would like to associate another phone number with that person. How did you intend on doing that?

Comment: Person table has composite primary key composed of (person_id, phone_id). That way Person can have multiple phone.

Comment: Let me write an answer to the question, it will be more readable that way

Answer (score 0):

There is a name clash in your mapping: `@JoinColumn (name="table1_id")` on `Table2.table1Set` vs `@Id @Column(name = "table1_id")` on `Table1.id`. Note that the join column goes into `Table1`, **not** `Table2`.

What you probably mean is a schema like this: `PERSON(id, name, age, a_bunch_of_other_stuff)`, `PERSON_PHONE_NUMBER(person_id, phone_id)`, `PHONE_NUMBER(id, phone_number)`, in which case your mapping should look like the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String name;
    ...

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "PERSON_PHONE_NUMBER", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PHONE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    )
    private Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "PHONE_NUMBER")
public class PhoneNumber {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER")
    private String phoneNumber;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.In my case , there is no JoinTable : PERSON_PHONE_NUMBER(person_id, phone_id) . My schema is something like this :   PERSON(id (primary key) , phone_id  (primary key),name, age, a_bunch_of_other_staff)  and  PHONE_NUMBER(id, phone_number).

Comment: The schema you describe doesn't make sense. It would mean whenever a person has more than one phone, the data of that person (name, age etc.) gets duplicated in the `PERSON` table. There is no way of mapping such a schema in JPA other than establishing a one-to-one relationship between `Person` and `PhoneNumber` and, well, accepting the fact that multiple `Person` entities will exist for a single actual person

Comment: Well of-course Phone and Person are just examples so it may seem that same data is duplicated.However in my case , the rows have different values of other columns for the different permutations of two Keys. There is no repetition of data in different rows.This actually makes me rethink the relationship is actually ManyToMany. Will check if the issue solves with that. Thanks!